# LiveData pause interrupts download thread and causes crash

Tags: multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2, android-livedata

My setup is the following

Activity:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  myViewModel.getData(intent.getParam).observe(this, this::dataDisplay);
}
```

ViewModel

```
getData(String param) {
  return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(repository.getData(param)
                .toFlowable());
}
```

Repository:

```
getData(String param) {
  return Single.fromCallable(() -> request.execute().fromJson())
      .doOnSuccess(this::cache)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO);
}
```

The problem is that for some reason, as soon as my activity gets created, it gets destroyed and recreated. Thus `onCreate` is called twice. The activity shutdown, causes livedata to send a dispose signal up, and that somehow causes the download thread to interrupt, which then throws an error

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:50)

Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:133)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:439)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse$SizeValidatingInputStream.read(NetHttpResponse.java:164)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:351)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:180)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1291)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1031)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:816)
```

Did anyone come through this problem and have a way forward?

Comment: Post the code you have in methods `request.execute().fromJson()` and `this::cache`. You are maybe violating reactive streams' rule that the producer is responsible for not emitting an item when a stream is canceled.

Comment: request.execute does the http call, and `fromJson` deserializes the response from the http call into objects. These are non reactive methods, and the bridge to make them reactive is `fromCallable` It's not that the producer is emitting items after the stream is cancelled, it's that the stream is cancelled, and then an exception is thrown, which cannot propogate since the stream is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a copy of `Single.fromCallable`, which would not crash if an exception was thrown inside the Callable after the Subscription is cancelled.